# Angular factory does not return array of objects but a single object

Tags: json, angularjs, csv, papaparse

I am new to angular and I am trying to load a CSV list inside a factory and then convert it to json. I am using Papaparse (CSV to json library) inside the factory. When I console log the factory I get the array of objects which is exactly what I want but when I pass it inside my controller I get a single object which holds all the data.

This is my factory

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('test');

  app.factory('testFactory', ['$http', function($http) {

    var url = 'my-list.csv';

    var getContact = function() {

        return $http.get(url).success(function(data) {
            Papa.parse(data, {
                header: true,
                complete: function(results) {
                    console.log(results.data);
                    return results.data;
                }
            });
        });
      };

      return {
        getContact: getContact
      };
  }]);
}());
```

And this is my controller

```js
(function() {

  var app = angular.module('test');

  app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', 'testFactory', function($scope, testFactory) {

    testFactory.getContact().then(function(data) {
         $scope.contacts = data;
         console.log(data);
     });
     
  }]);

}());
```

I want be able to do something like this inside my view

```
{{ contact.firstname }}
```

Comment: So `console.log(results.data)` from the factory gives you something different than `console.log(data)` from the controller?

Comment: Sorry yes they are different. Factory results returns Array of objects and the controller returns a single object with all the data in.

Comment: I think it will work if you change `$http.get(url).success` to `$http.get(url).then` in the factory

Comment: I get this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Comment: Can you show the output of the console statements?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at FileStreamer._readChunk (papaparse.js:613)
    at FileStreamer._nextChunk (papaparse.js:604)
    at FileStreamer.stream (papaparse.js:598)
    at Object.CsvToJson [as parse] (papaparse.js:212)
    at services.js:12
    at angular.js:14569
    at n.$get.n.$eval (angular.js:15848)
    at n.$get.n.$digest (angular.js:15659)
    at n.$get.n.$apply (angular.js:15953)
    at l (angular.js:10366)

Comment: Hmm, not sure why changing to `.then` would've affected that.  Maybe you need to papaparse `data.data`?  Make sure the value you're passing is the same as it was before

Comment: data.data did the trick and its now rendering the object again but the controller console.log give me undefined now. Any ideas? I really appreciate your help on this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tom This is probably better. The core problem was bad chaining of promises. To solve the undefined issue you have to add an additional `return`. [This plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fzvoGJJH3zxVPNhatMBP?p=preview) shows that strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the order of resolution. Inspecting the console statements shows that you're assigning `$scope.contacts` to the resolution of the `$http.get` promise, and not the actual parsing.

Instead of returning the `$http.get` promise, return a deferred promise and resolve at the end of parsing:

```
var parsePromise = $q.defer();
$http.get(url).success(function(data) {
    Papa.parse(data, {
        header: true,
        complete: function(results) {
            console.log(results.data);
            parsePromise.resolve(results.data);
        }
    });
});
return parsePromise.promise;
```

See working demo [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fzvoGJJH3zxVPNhatMBP?p=info).

**Update**: As per the comments, you could use `.then` to chain promises instead of creating a new `deferred`. The plunkr has both, you can use the changelog to toggle methods.

Comment: Thank you so much!! That is exactly what I was looking for. Can't thank you enough really!!

Comment: No problem. I've updated [the plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/fzvoGJJH3zxVPNhatMBP?p=preview) to use the `.then` strategy. You can compare using the plunkr changelog.

Comment: In your opinion which is best for my case and best practice in general? They both seem to work quite well.

Comment: The following is my opinion: the `$q.defer` is more explicit in what's happening. If Papa supported promises natively you should `.then` chain all the way. I would say `.then` chaining is the best practice, but since the callback breaks the promise chain it's really a toss-up.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and assistance.  God bless you :D